# Chain of Map method references

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm working with Twitter4J. But the question I'm asking is more general. I want to access the user id of a given tweet. Currently, I have the following two options:

```
//Option 1
stream.map(status -> status.getUser().getId())
      .forEach(System.out::println);

//Option 2:
stream.map(Status::getUser)
      .map(User:getId)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

I don't like the lambda expression in the first option, nor being forced to call two `maps` in the second one. Is there a way to make a chain of method references? I know that `Status::getUser::getId` does not work, but am wondering if there is an alternative.

Comment: Why you don't like 2 `map` calls? Do you worry about performance? You don't have to - the stream will be processed in one pass.

Comment: Verbosity. For the same reason `status.getUser().getId()` exists, I hoped that something like `Status::getUser::getId` exists.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Nope, these are the two ways of doing it.  Anything else would end up being only less clear.

But, since you asked, here are some options.

```
static<T,U,R> Function<T,R> chain(
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> f1,
        Function<? super U, ? extends R> f2) {
    return t -> f2.apply(f1.apply(t));
}

stream.map(chain(Status::getUser, User::getId))
```

Or

```
static<T,R> Function<T,R> func(Function<T,R> f) {
    return f;
}

stream.map(func(Status::getUser).andThen(User::getId))
```

Comment: Actually, both approaches do what calling `map` twice does, the only difference being that the stream will always use `Function.andThen` or `Function.compose` instead of re-implementing it itself (like your `chain` method).

Comment: I was looking for something that avoids calling the class `User`, because it should be inferred directly from `getUser`. I accept "Nope" as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Of the two options proposed, I tend to use the second, chaining calls to `map()`.

There are other options, which uses built-in API instead of helper methods, as shown [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26922740/3474) With the [`Function.compose()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#compose-java.util.function.Function-) or [`Function.andThen()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#andThen-java.util.function.Function-) methods, you can chain function invocations. `Predicate` and other functional interfaces implement similar default methods.

```
stream.map(((Function<Status, User>) Status::getUser).andThen(User::getId))
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Alternatively

```
Function<Status, User> toUser = Status::getUser;
stream.map(toUser.andThen(User::getId)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

The drawback is that, in order to use these, the functional interface type has to be given explicitly. That requires a cast or an assignment, and that looks a bit ugly. So for a mapping chain, I usually use multiple `map()` calls.