# java8: method reference from another method reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I want to use a method reference based off another method reference.  It's kind of hard to explain, so I'll give you an example:

**Person.java**

```
public class Person{
    Person sibling;
    int age;

    public Person(int age){
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setSibling(Person p){
        this.sibling = p;
    }

    public Person getSibling(){
        return sibling;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }
}
```

Given a list of `Person`s, I want to use method references to get a list of their sibling's ages.  I know this can be done like this:

```
roster.stream().map(p -> p.getSibling().getAge()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I'm wondering if it's possible to do it more like this:

```
roster.stream().map(Person::getSibling::getAge).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It's not terribly useful in this example, I just want to know what's possible.

Comment: [Chain of Map method references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920866/chain-of-map-method-references)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use two [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) operations in that case:

```
roster.stream().map(Person::getSibling).map(Person::getAge).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The first one maps the `Person` to its sibling and the second one maps the `Person` to its age.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Functions.chain()` from [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) to chain method references:

```
MutableList<Person> roster = Lists.mutable.empty();
MutableList<Integer> ages = 
    roster.collect(Functions.chain(Person::getSibling, Person::getAge));
```

If you can’t change roster from `List`

```
List<Person> roster = Lists.mutable.empty();
List<Integer> ages =
    ListAdapter.adapt(roster).collect(Functions.chain(Person::getSibling, Person::getAge));
```

Since age is an `int`, you can avoid boxing by using an [IntList](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/list/primitive/IntList.html):

```
MutableList<Person> roster = Lists.mutable.empty();
IntList ages = roster.collectInt(Functions.chainInt(Person::getSibling, Person::getAge));
```

Note: I am a contributor to Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 2):

Use Function.andThen, and possibly wrap your first method reference in a call, or cast.

```
public static <V, R> Function<V,R> ofFunction(Function<V,R> function) {
    return function;
}

roster.collect(ofFunction(Person::getSibling).andThen(Person::getAge));
```