# Java 8 method reference

Tags: java, java-8

In Java 8 is it possible to call 2 reference methods in a row?

```
customer::new::getName
```

Can be concatenated 2 methods reference of the form:

```
a::b::c
```

Comment: No, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920866/chain-of-map-method-references for ideas for alternatives.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chain of Map method references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920866/chain-of-map-method-references)

Comment: What’s wrong with `()->new customer().getName()` or `()->a.b().c()`?

Answer (score 3):

### How to inline two method reference expression ?

Let's decomposing `Customer::new::getName` expression;

```
T1 customer = Customer::new;
T2 name = customer::getName;
```

according [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2) described Method Reference Expression,so `T1` and `T2` must are [FunctionalInterface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html).

> A method reference expression is compatible in an assignment context, invocation context, or casting context with a target type T if T is a functional interface type (§9.8) and the expression is congruent with the function type of the ground target type derived from T.

when you use `Supplier<Customer>` with `T1` then the compiler reports error:**can't resolve method getName defined on Supplier**. but you can define your own FunctionalInterface, e.g: `CustomerSupplier`.

```
interface CustomerSupplier {
    Customer get();

    default String getName() {
        return get().getName();
    }
}
```

then you can refer `Customer::new` to `CustomerSupplier`:

```
CustomerSupplier customer = Customer::new;
Supplier<String> name = customer::getName;
```

Indeed, you can inline two expression together in further, but each method reference expression must be a FunctionalInterface, so you must cast `Customer::new` to `CustomerSupplier`.

```
Supplier<String> customerName = ((CustomerSupplier) Customer::new)::getName;
```

**However**, the simplest one is access directly that provided by [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger).

```
Supplier<String> customerName = () -> new Customer().getName();
```

### How to chain two method reference expression ?

Due to `Supplier` has no methods for composing FunctionInterface, but you can chain the method reference expression like this:

```
interface Reference<T> extends Supplier<T> {
    static <T> Reference<T> of(Supplier<T> reference) {
        return reference::get;
    }

    default <R> Reference<R> of(Function<T, R> after) {
        return () -> after.apply(get());
    }
}

//NOTE:Reference is derived from Supplier, so it is compatible with Supplier.  
Supplier<String> customerName = Reference.of(Customer::new).of(Customer::getName);
```

**However**, you can introduce a method to avoid introduce a type for composing Function Interfaces that provided by [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger).

```
private <T, R> Supplier<R> map(Supplier<T> target, Function<T, R> mapper) {
    return () -> mapper.apply(target.get());
}

Supplier<String> customerName = map(Customer::new, Customer::getName);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, **you can't chain** two method references.

Basically, a **method reference is a syntactic sugar which will allow you to pass the definition of an existing method to a Lambda expression** (which implements single `abstract` method).

Answer (score 1):

> In Java 8 is it possible to call 2 reference methods in a row?

No, it's not possible to chain methods when using method references because a method reference is essentially a shorthand syntax for a lambda expression that executes just **ONE** method. Hence, once you start chaining methods it would no longer be valid syntax for a method reference.

**syntax**

```
Object::methodName
```